# How should I load a node with its images programatically?

Tags: nodes, media

I want to load a node with its images in Drupal 7, such as using the following code:

```
  $current_node = node_load(arg(1));
  db_query("SELECT nid, title FROM {node} WHERE type = :type AND created < :created LIMIT 1", array(':type' =>  $current_node->type, ':created' => $current_node->created))->fetchObject()
```

I wish to load the image field in the content; I think I should use left join to load the image file.

Does anybody know what to do next? What is the image table name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to join another table for every field that you want to grab the data for, which is just a pain. Instead, you could just get the `nid` with your query, and use [`node_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load/7) a second time to get the other node object, complete with attached fields.

You can do that like so:

```
$args = array(':type' => $current_node->type, ':created' => $current_node->created);
$sql = 'SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE type = :type AND created < :created';
$nid = db_query_range($sql, 0, 1, $args)->fetchField();

$new_node = node_load($nid);

$title = $node->title;
$image_field_values = field_get_items('node', $new_node, 'field_image');

$first_image = array_shift($image_field_values);
$image_file = file_load($first_image['fid']);

$image_html = theme('image_style', array(
  'style_name' => 'thumbnail',
  'path' => $image_file->uri,
  'alt' => 'Some alt text'
));

$body_values = field_get_items('node', $new_node, 'body');

// And so on
```

Comment: because I need to theme the image by using theme('image_style', array('style_name' => 'thumbnail', 'path' => url);  so I need to know the path of the image, how can I extract the image url from the variable $image_field_values?

Comment: I've put an example in the answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Yes and to add more to it, if you use node load it is safer because then the Drupal caching will by default will work for you. And if you are writing queries to get the result then every time the page is going to get a hit, the query will be fired and no caching will be done by default. You have to explicitly handle the caching at this point of time.